# Using Mongoose $push into Array Schema type

Tags: node.js, mongoose, restify

I have the following Users and Posts schemas, which Users has the following data type:

```
postCreated:{
    type: Array,
    default: []
}
```

And the server route for Posts is:

```
server.post('/posts',(req,res,next) => {
    const {username,title,categories,content} = req.body;
    const post = new Posts({
        username,
        title,
        categories,
        content
    });
    post.save().then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc);
        res.send(doc);
        User.findOneAndUpdate({username}, {$push: {'postCreated': doc}});
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        return next(new errors.BadRequestError(e.message));
    });
});
```

Which saves the newly created post into the database and update the 'postCreated' property in the User schema. However, my current code does not work, is there any way that I could do pushing that newly created post into the 'Post Created' Array?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this will work for you:

```
server.post('/posts',(req,res,next) => {
    const {username,title,categories,content} = req.body;
    const post = new Posts({
        username,
        title,
        categories,
        content
    });
    return post.save()
      .then(doc => User.findOneAndUpdate({username}, {$push: {'postCreated': doc}})
        .then(() => res.send(doc)))
    .catch(e => {
        return next(new errors.BadRequestError(e.message));
    });
});
```

You ware missing the returns for the `post.save` as well as for the `User.findOneAndUpdate`. Also your the `res.send(doc)` should probably be the last thing in your function.